# Enhanced Domains - What to Check in your Org?

Tags: salesforce, appdomain, release-notes

As you know Salesforce is enforcing Enhanced Domains. I found from Salesforce help that:

- Custom components in your org must be evaluated in order to check
  whether they use domain name/static URLs
- Some embedded content stored in Salesforce might no longer appear
- Third-party applications can lose access to your data
- Single sign-on integrations can fail

However, I'm struggling with finding out which particular Salesforce elements/configurations should be checked in order to detect potential gaps? Do you know which areas exactly can be affected and shall be evaluated (like Apex Codes, Email Templates and so on)? Is there any guide on that?

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest concern should be inbound integrations. Things that log in over REST/SOAP API, get response with session id back, ignore the "url to use for all subsequent requests" and just use hardcoded url, whether it's prod or sandbox.

Look at this guy, he's victim of either enhanced domain or "disable api versions < 30" thing: [The requested resource no longer exists with rest PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73192046/313628). Look at these guys, they had hardcoded url: [how to solve python code error (TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74087168/313628), [Salesforce API via postman error INVALID_SESSION_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74016162/313628).

As for stuff inside Salesforce itself - best would be to download whole project with sfdx and run a text search for your domain name (and site/community name if you have these). Email templates that use merge fields for forgot password etc should be fine, merge fields with record link should be fine... But if you manually craft email body in apex - might be a problem. A lot depends how creative the developer was. If you find `getsalesforcebaseurl().toexternalform()` it should still work. If it's hardcoded / read from custom setting / custom label / custom metadata it might be more fun.

If you have external apps that display pieces of salesforce (embedded live chat? some iframe with FAQ? CMS Connect) - the domain change might mean they need to be updated, both in terms of updating url and changing security rules (CSP for example)